# UIWebView only works when added to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsobject

I am wanting to use a `UIWebView` to do some manipulation of a web page.
I've added all the necessary `UIWebView` code to an `NSObject` class but the `UIWebView` delegate methods are never called and it seems to not do anything at all.

If I transfer the exact same code to a `UIViewController` class and add the `UIWebView` to the view, it works fine.

So does a UIWebView even work if it's not added to a view?
How can I add this with a zero frame or hidden from an `NSObject` class?

I've really cut down my code (below) which should work as it is but doesn't.

`MyWebViewHelper.m`

```
@interface MyWebViewHelper () <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (strong) UIWebView *webview;
@end

- (instancetype)initWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString username:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)readPage
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    self.webview=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    _webview.delegate = self;
    [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegates

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Should start loading: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);

    NSLog(@"Headers: %@",[request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    NSLog(@"Method: %@",[request HTTPMethod]);

    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
}
```

Comment: How were you doing it before - not adding it to a UIViewController? Just like any UIView it's gotta be added to a VC in order to be seen.

Comment: I don't need it to be seen. I just need to use the UIWebView to run some javascript on a page. But it doesn't seem to load the page unless it's added to a view

Comment: AH, no, it doesn't work that way. Have you tried `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`?

Comment: That's what I need to use, but it needs a UIWebView to load a page first which doesn't seem to happen unless added to a view.

Comment: What about firing an NSURLRequest to get the contents of the page and then execute it?

Comment: I need to eventually hit a submit form button on the page, so need it running in a UIWebView to execute `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.forms[0].submit();"];` I might just have to forget about separating it into it's own class and run it all from the `UIViewController`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution to this. `UIWebView` does in fact work without being added to a view. For some reason, my `NSObject` class running the `UIWebView` was being deallocated by `ARC`.
I only found this out when trying to get the class to add the `UIWebView` to a view and it kept crashing but wouldn't give me any reasons or breakpoint.

I eventually figured out to enable zombie objects and it complained about sending a message to a deallocated instance.

Anyway, the fix turned out to be adding a `strong` property reference to my class to stop it being deallocated like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyWebViewHelper *myWebHelper;
```